# Best generator for a modern front-end web module?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

What is the best generator/scaffold for a modern front-end web module with npm/webpack?

Answer (score 1):

There are a plethora of different generator and scaffolding tools using all of the latest and greatest technologies however there is no "best" one. You'll find multiple depending on what your needs are, it really comes down to what your current architecture looks like and what you would like to build with.

It's a personal preference and different for every use case, no one can recommend you the best.

Did a quick Google search ("popular scaffolding tools web dev") and found these: [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), [Slush](https://modernweb.com/slush-a-better-web-app-scaffolding-tool/)

Edit: It should be noted [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) is a scaffolding tool with a variety of custom built generators for different use cases - this could be a good start.